# same table join

Tags: mysql

Table employee has ssn and superssn coloumns. I want to show the supervisor of the supervisor of each employee (or null if none exists). So far I only have the supervisors of each employee:

```
SELECT p.fname AS sup,
group_concat(c.fname) AS emp 
FROM employee AS p
LEFT JOIN employee AS c 
ON (p.ssn = c.superssn) 
GROUP BY p.ssn;
```

Should I do another `JOIN`? Or something in `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the manager, employee and then the manager's supervisor, then you can join on the table `employee` multiple times:

```
SELECT p.fname AS sup,   -- Manager
    group_concat(c.fname) AS emp,  -- Employees
    sp.fname as SuperSuper   -- Manager Supervisor
FROM employee AS p
LEFT JOIN employee AS c 
    ON p.ssn = c.superssn
LEFT JOIN employee sp
    on p.superssn = sp.ssn
GROUP BY p.ssn;
```

Comment: THANKS. I didn't know how to do the double joins. I see now how the sp variable helps.

Comment: @broinjc happy to help.  If this or any of the answers to your questions are acceptable, then be sure to accept via the checkmark to the left of it. It will help future visitors and you get site rep for accepting.